# Dataframe Pivot Index contains duplicate entries

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, indexing, pivot, pivot-table

I am currently using dataframe pivot function as below, but I am getting below error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Serialno': [1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1]    
                   'position': ['G', 'G', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'F', 'F'],
                   'points': [5, 7, 7, 9, 4, 9, 9, 12]})

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Code below:

```
df.pivot_table(index='team', columns='position', values='points')
```

When I researched this online I found the root cause is duplicate in data for same index, column combination and below is the fix suggested.

```
df.pivot_table(index='team', columns='position', values='points', aggfunc='sum')
```

But in my scenario, I need to apply aggregate function on a new column (which is not part of columns, values). I have a serialno column and in case of duplicate I need to pick the value which has higher serialno.

in above example I want this output :

```
position    F    G
team        
A           7   7
B           9   9
```

Please advise on how to handle this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

I think that one way to make it work is to parse the values before creating a pivot table. You can get just the values for the highest `Serialno` from the `df`. See the example below.

Edit:

Code below now gets highest `Serialno` for each team, saves it's index and then creates new `df_final` out of those. I believe that then you can create the pivot on this data, but I'm not sure about choosing different columns depending on the different values, so you would probably need to experiment with this.

```
>>> max_index = []
>>> for t in df['team'].unique():
...     max_index += (df[(df['team'] == t) & (df['Serialno'] == (df[df['team'] == t]['Serialno'].max()))].index).tolist()
... 
>>> df_final = df[df.index.isin(max_index)]
>>> df_final
  team  Serialno position  points
1    A         2        G       7
2    A         2        F       7
5    B         2        G       9
6    B         2        F       9
>>>
```

Comment: Serialno is different for each team, and based on max serialno for each team I also need to pick values column in my result dataset and then do Pivot. Can you please suggest.